# makers are calling the same activity on google maps

Tags: java, android, maps, markers

I have a little problem with applying makers on Google maps to call activities.
I can successfully create the points and even call the activitys by clicking them, but the problem is that they are always calling the same activity no matter what I do.
Can someone help me?

Already tried to move the variables, already tried to move the celula01 variable to see makes a connection, but none of this gives any return.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap, mCel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mCel = googleMap;

    LatLng celula04 = new LatLng(-23.174601, -45.839513);
    mCel.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(celula04).title("Célula da Maria"));
    mCel.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(celula04));
    mCel.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Celula02.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }
    });

    LatLng celula01 = new LatLng(-23.173300, -45.821273);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(celula01).title("Célula do Rafael"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(celula01));
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Celula01.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }
    });

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: why do you have two map activity in one mapFragment mMap, mcel..use one and set different marker location

Comment: You can only have one marker listener for a map - `mMap` and `mCel` are the same map so in your code it will always start the `Celula01` activity.  You can use `setTag` and `getTag` on a marker to distnguish between markers on click.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnMarkerClickListener,
    OnMapReadyCallback {

private static final LatLng celula04 = new LatLng(-23.174601, -45.839513);
private static final LatLng celula01 = new LatLng(-23.173300, -45.821273);


private Marker mcelula04;
private Marker mcelula01;

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.marker_demo);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

/** Called when the map is ready. */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;

    // Add some markers to the map, and add a data object to each marker.
    mcelula04 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(celula04)
            .title("Célula da Maria");
    mcelula04.setTag(1);

    mcelula01 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(celula01)
            .title("Célula do Rafael");
    mcelula01.setTag(2);


    // Set a listener for marker click.
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
}

/** Called when the user clicks a marker. */
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

    // Retrieve the data from the marker.
    Integer click = (Integer) marker.getTag();

    // Check if a click count was set, then display the click count.
    if (click = 1) {
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Celula02.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }elseif(click = 2){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Celula01.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    // Return false to indicate that we have not consumed the event and that we wish
    // for the default behavior to occur (which is for the camera to move such that the
    // marker is centered and for the marker's info window to open, if it has one).
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Still keeps calling the same activity on both makers